# Using .gesture(LongPressGesture) break the Scrollview

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, swift5, gesture

I'm using Swift 5, SwiftUI 3.0 on Xcode 13.2.

I have the following code:

```
  ZStack { ... custom button }
 .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 30)
        .onEnded { _ in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                    // code when ended...
                }
        }
        .onChanged { _ in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                // code when touched...
            }
            
        })
```

Let's call this `CustomButton`.

I then have this ScrollView and LazyVGrid:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 15) {
           let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), count: 1)

           LazyVGrid(columns: columns,spacing: 15) {
               CustomButton()
               CustomButton()
               // and then some more...
           }
    } 
}
```

Now when I remove the `onChange` handler from CustomButton, the scrolling works fine. So I am guessing, that since `onChange()` fires as soon as I tap the button, it takes precedence over the `ScrollView`. However, I need the animation that occurs after `onChange()` is fired, or after the user touches the button.

I've tried having an empty `.onTapGesture {}` before the `.gesture()` modifier.
I've tried changing `.gesture` to `.simulatenousGesture`
And I've tried most anything I can find on SO or the AppleDev forums.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a button in a ScrollView, that:

1. Accepts 0.0 `minimumDuration` touch, or `.gesture().onChange`
2. Is still scrollable in ScrollView

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This variation works (don't ask me why...):

```
struct CustomButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .frame(height: 50)
        
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tapped")
            }
        
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 30) {
                print("longpress ended")
            } onPressingChanged: { pressing in
                print("longpress changed")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused, but it works perfectly  thanks Chris!